# Mapping: Default value across databases

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm mapping a class with NHibernate, but I use the same map over 2 different databases.
This works on Sybase Anywhere, but doesn't work on SQLite.

This is my map class:

```
public FooMap()
{
    Property(x => x.Date, map =>
    {
        map.Column(c => c.Default("now(*)"));
        map.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Insert);
        map.NotNullable(true);
    });
}
```

and this is the mapper:

```
public class Provider
{
    public void AddMappings(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseMap)).GetExportedTypes().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Map")));
    }
}
```

SQlite doesn't have NOW function, so this cause a error when Hibernate try to create this table.

How can I insert a default value according with the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using StructureMapMVC so i did this:

```
var db = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Provider>();

if (db == null)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException("Service Provider not found.");
}

if (db is SybaseProvider)
{
    map.Column(c => c.Default("now(*)"));
}
else // SQLite
{
    map.Column(c => c.Default("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"));
}
map.Generated(PropertyGeneration.Insert);
map.NotNullable(true);
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that different databases use different functions in generating datetime default values, I would adopt the approach of generating the values at object initialization time.

You may wish to look at [Default Value does not work with DateTime and Fluent Nhibernate 1.2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fluent-nhibernate/3piNzF6CEMw) forum thread which has the following as part of the answer:

> To specify a default value for a property/field, just assign it like
>   you would a normal field; set it in the field definition or in the
>   constructor of your entity, nothing fancy required.

Following this approach will allow working with different databases without worrying about how they generate their datetime default values.